# How to close a session connection properly with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm closing the session but the connections are still sleep in MySQL for around one hour. The issue is that I have too many connections sleep after a while. I am using Python3, PyMySQL 1.0.2 and SQLAlchemy 2.0.0 with the following code.

```
import pymysql.cursors
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


connect_string = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}@/{db_name}?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{cloudsql_instance}"
engine = create_engine(connect_string, echo=False, pool_recycle=30,pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)


session = sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=True, autoflush=True, autocommit=False)
session.configure(bind=engine())
session = session()

all_users = session.execute(text('SELECT employee_name FROM users WHERE status='1';')).fetchall()
print(all_users)

session.close()
```

Comment: `Session.close()` does not close the connection. You can use `session.connection().close()` to close it, but I don't think it is necessary, since your `pool_recycle` is already set to 30 seconds (just recycle connections?).  What adverse effect does it have on your app? I wonder why you'd want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in last

```
engine.dispose()
```

```
import pymysql.cursors
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


connect_string = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}@/{db_name}?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{cloudsql_instance}"
engine = create_engine(connect_string, echo=False, pool_recycle=30,pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)


session = sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=True, autoflush=True, autocommit=False)
session.configure(bind=engine())
session = session()

all_users = session.execute(text('SELECT employee_name FROM users WHERE status='1';')).fetchall()
print(all_users)

session.close()


# Explicitly dispose of the engine to close all connections in the connection pool
engine.dispose()
```